# mod_rewrite to direct some requests to a new directory

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a website with a frontend and a backend that all run through index.php. To access the back end you would go to http://www.mysite.com/Admin. This will still run through index.php but then connect to the database and go to the correct directory. The backend manages donation information that is collected on the site.

I want to change the front end to WordPress but still collect donation information in the original database and view it from the backend.

Rather than rewrite all the code, I was wondering if there was a way I could use mod-rewrite and place the WordPress files in a separate directory. This way any request that included /Admin as the start would go through the original index.php and any other request would redirect to directory with WordPress.

I originally tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ gpf/$1 [L]
```

but a request for /Admin just gives me a 404 error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

This is the full .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

# Serve 'gate' as php
<Files gate>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>

FileETag MTime Size
AddCharset UTF-8 .xml

AddType video/mp4  mp4 m4v
AddType audio/mp4  m4a
AddType video/ogg  ogv
AddType audio/ogg  ogg oga
AddType video/webm webm

# redirect all domains (.net, .com, .biz, etc) to .org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.org/$1 [R=301,L]

# Route search
RewriteRule ^search$ /search/ [R,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ gpf/$1 [L]

# Route domain plus slash correctly
RewriteRule  ^$ /gate/ [L]

# All requests: serve _gate_ as php. 1st arg is requested URL qs preserved
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Z].*) /gate/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^rss\.xml /gate/rss.xml [QSA,L]

# PHP directives - should comment out on production server
php_value display_errors 1
php_value display_startup_errors 1

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript text/plain


<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On

# Manually change filenames for static images. CMS changes names in dyn
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 9 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 9 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 9 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 9 months"

# Rare changes. manually change filename

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 9 months"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 9 months"

# PDFs should never change. CMS renames in dyn
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-pdf "access plus 6 months"

# Frequent changes. ASFU dynamic rename
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 6 months"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where/what are the rest of your rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an additional condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gate
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gpf/$1 [L]
```

And move the rules after all of the `/gate/` rules.

Comment: Thank you so much. adding the additional condition did the trick. I needed to keep it before the /gate/ rules though or else requests for front end pages ran through the gate as well.